# Panning fullscreen image with jquery, while remain centered

Tags: jquery, pan

The fullscreen background is centered with

```
background: url(image) no-repeat center center;
```

Now I want the background image to move slightly whenever the user moves the mouse. I've come across several ways / plugins to do this, but not quite as I wanted so I chose to do it like this (which I also found somewhere):

```
$("body").bind('mousemove', function(e){
    var ypos=(e.pageY-100)/12 + 10;
    var xpos=(e.pageX-100)/18 + 10;
    $(this).css({backgroundPosition: xpos * (-1) + 'px ' + ypos * (-1) + 'px' });
});
```

The different values (/12, +10) are just values I arbitrarly chose because they gave me the result I was looking for - not sure if it's the right way to do.
Anyway, the problem now is that when the page loads from scratch (without moving the mouse) everything looks fine (images centered).

If the script posted above is enabled and you move the mouse the background image "jumps" somewhere (according to the position values), so it shows from the very top left of the image which it shouldn't.

Unfortunately I can't code myself (just edit some basic stuff) and always was bad at math. This obviously is "just" a math problem, but can anyone help me figuring out what I would have to change, so the background image basically always is centered, but moves only slightly 50px (or whatever) in all directions?

Basically something like this http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_image_panning_liquid.html, but not with an actual image but css / background only.

Comment: you've to calculate the _amount of mouse move_ but e.pageX/Y gives you absolute position of the mouse cursor. That's your problem

Comment: Do you maybe have any example for this? Since unfortunately I have no idea how to achieve this... Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://www.bratzillaz.com/en-us/section/bios/cloetta  You might have to make a containing DIV that has a background image where you can move that div around instead of moving the body around

Comment: Something similar, yes. Though the example probably would be "overkill" for my use since I just need one fullscreen image to pan slightly - another issue is to always have the same "movement". So far examples like http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_image_panning_liquid.html move very differently with different resolutions (way more in 1024 than in 1920)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting the code, that I've cooked up quickly, in the answers section to maintain readability. This *might* solve your issue indirectly.

```
    $(function(){
        var mousex = mousey = null;
        $('body').mousemove(function(ev){
           if(mousex === null || mousey === null){
              //get initial x/y position for mouse cursor
              mousex = ev.pageX;
              mousey = ev.pageY;
           }

           window.clearTimeout(window.mouse_timeout);

           window.mouse_timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
              console.log('mouse moved', ev.pageX - mousex, ev.pageY - mousey);

              /* now that you've the absolute position of the mouse and delta x/y here, you can move your background accordingly */

              //update the variables to the latest picket position of the mouse
              mousex = ev.pageX;
              mousey = ev.pageY;
           }, 10)
        });
     });
```

---

### Update

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s84rJ/) This code marks the initial mouse position as *center* reference point and calculates mouse movement with reference to that point later on.

### Markup

```
<div id="outer_container">
    <div id="imagePan">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="mov">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/92Z5zCM.jpg" class="panning" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
html, body{ height: 100%; }
body{ margin: 0; padding: 0; background: #eee; }
#outer_container{ position: relative; margin: auto; padding: 4px; border: 8px solid #dadada; height: 90%; width: 80%; background: #CDD7E0}
#imagePan{ position: relative; overflow: hidden; cursor: crosshair; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
#imagePan .container{ position: relative; left: 0; }
#mov{ margin: -51px -391px 0 }
```

### Javascript

```
     var originX = originY = xUnit = yUnit = dX = dY = mov = null;
     $(window).load(function () {
        mov = $('#mov');
        initMarginL = parseInt(mov.css('margin-left'));
        initMarginT = parseInt(mov.css('margin-top'));

        $('#outer_container').mousemove(function (ev) {
           if (originX === null || originY === null) {
              originX = ev.pageX;
              originY = ev.pageY;

              xUnit = parseFloat((Math.max(originX, $(window).width()) / $(window).width()).toFixed(2));
              yUnit = parseFloat((Math.max(originY, $(window).height()) / $(window).height()).toFixed(2));
           }

           var dX = originX - ev.pageX;
           var dY = originY - ev.pageY;

           mov.css({
              marginLeft: initMarginL + (dX * xUnit),
              marginTop: initMarginT + (dY * yUnit)
           });
        });
     });
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and posting the code! I'm not sure if I would have to add anything but if I just replace the old code with this one nothing seems to happen/move unfortunately.

Comment: This wouldn't, _out of the box_. You'll need to _incorporate_ this code into your code

Comment: Sorry for asking again, so I probably have to use "$(this).css({backgroundPosition: mousex + 'px ' + mousey + 'px' });" somehow?

Comment: No, it'll still jump IMO. The idea I had in my mind is that you could set the initial mouse position as the _center_ for calculating delta_x and delta_y and move the background accordingly. This is not an answer to move your background, it lets you calculate _amount_ of mouse movement since last 10ms. I thought you could utilize it if you saw it fit :) BTW the liquid demo does jump in firefox 20.0.1

Comment: Okay, thanks - Shouldn't there be some kind of way though where you just use the code posted, but subtract (or add or whatever) something, so the image doesn't always jumps to the top left? :(

Comment: @Simon in case you're still interested, check my update. I've copied the (only) HTML straight from your reference site so it might not make sense :D The javascript alters the `margin-left` and `margin-top` of the _movable_ element. I hope you can adapt it to move your desired element.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will try it at home in the evening.

Answer (score 1):

Since "center center" is obviously the same as "50% 50%" I think I just found out the answer! :)

```
$('body').mousemove(function(e){
  var mousePosX = 50 + (e.pageX/$(window).width())*10;
  var mousePosY = 50 + (e.pageY/$(window).height())*5;
  $(this).css('backgroundPosition', mousePosX + '% ' +  mousePosY + '%');
});
```

Still moves too fast with smaller resolutions (than 1920) but that aside it works.